# Bloc not adding widget to list?

Tags: flutter, bloc

im trying to make  a list builder with bloc that adds a widget to make variants of a product, but when i press the button it wont add a new widget, it should be more clear with the images. Size is not the issue since

This is the code with the bloc builder

```
class MarketplaceAddServiceForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MarketplaceAddServiceForm({
    Key? key,
    required GlobalKey<FormState> formKey,
    required this.usecase,
    required this.addServiceProvider,
  })  : _formKey = formKey,
        super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;
  final AddServiceUsecase usecase;
  final RegisterServiceBloc addServiceProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    return BlocConsumer<RegisterServiceBloc, RegisterServiceState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) {
        return current is SuccessRegisterServiceState ||
            current is ErrorRegisterServiceState;
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        validateServiceForm(state, context);
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 2)),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 2)),
          width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 80),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        const VerticalSpace(),
                        const VerticalSpace(),

                        Row(children: [
                          MarketplaceAddServiceNameTextfield(
                              controller: usecase.name),
                          MarketplaceChooseTypeService()
                        ]),

                        
                        BlocBuilder<AddVariantBloc, AddVariantState>(
                          buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is VariantAddedState,
                          builder: (context, state) {
                            if(state is VariantAddedState){
                            return Column(
                              children: (List.generate(
                                state.variants.length,
                                (index) =>
                                    Container(child: state.variants[index]),
                              )),
                            );
                            } return VariantTextfield(usecase: usecase);
                          },
                        ),

                        const VerticalSpace(),
                        const VerticalSpace(),

                        MarketplaceAddProductVariantButton(),
```

```
BlocBuilder<AddVariantBloc, AddVariantState>(
                          buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is VariantAddedState,
                          builder: (context, state) {
                            if(state is VariantAddedState){
                            return Column(
                              children: (List.generate(
                                state.variants.length,
                                (index) =>
                                    Container(child: state.variants[index]),
                              )),
                            );
                            } return VariantTextfield(usecase: usecase);
                          },
                        ),
```

The button that should add a new one.

```
InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              var usecase = AddServiceUsecase();
              variants.add(VariantTextfield(usecase: usecase));
              BlocProvider.of<AddVariantBloc>(context).add(VariantAddedEvent(variants: variants ));
            
            },
```

blocs

```
class AddVariantBloc extends Bloc<AddVariantEvent, AddVariantState> {
  AddVariantBloc() : super(AddVariantInitial()) {
    on<VariantAddedEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(VariantAddedState(variants: event.variants));
    });
  }
}
```

```
abstract class AddVariantEvent extends Equatable {
  const AddVariantEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class VariantAddedEvent extends AddVariantEvent {

  List variants;
  VariantAddedEvent({
    required this.variants,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [variants];

}
```

```
abstract class AddVariantState extends Equatable {
  const AddVariantState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddVariantInitial extends AddVariantState {}

class VariantAddedState extends AddVariantState {

  List variants;
  
  VariantAddedState({
    required this.variants,
  });

 @override
  List<Object> get props => [variants];
}
```

This is how it should work:

[image: You press the button.]

[image: And it should add 1 more]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Equatable properties should always be copied rather than modified. If
> an Equatable class contains a List or Map as properties, be sure to
> use List.from or Map.from respectively to ensure that equality is
> evaluated based on the values of the properties rather than the
> reference.

Equatable will see the `VariantAddedState` as equal each time thus the bloc will not rebuild the state, either use `List.from` as mentioned in their docs

i.e `emit(VariantAddedState(variants: List.from(event.variants)));`

or you can emit another temp State before emitting `VariantAddedState`